# What is "chat with an expert"

Tags: discussion

Today when I was browsing some older post on EL&U SE, a window with the words *"chat with an expert", "not now", and "never"* suddenly showed up. Out of curiosity, I clicked on "chat with an expert" and there is another window popped up, and this 'expert' was chatting with me.

[image]

What is going on here?

[This](http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/Cu4pVWGBMkKC) is a transcript of the chat (they called it "Ongoing support chat" but I swear the words beside the photo was "An expert" when I chatted with her [or him].)

I accidentally clicked on a link before asking her another question and now I can no longer get to contact with this expert again.

What triggers the "chat with an expert" window to show up? Does this happen randomly?

---

It suddenly showed up again!

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert

Comment: Apparently, it’s already April 1ˢᵗ in certain parts of the world.

Comment: I asked my expert if he/she was willing to take a [Turing test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test), but it declined.

Comment: It doesn't seem to understand "Never", either. A pretty dumb bot.

Comment: @JohnLawler Agree, dumb bots are typically pretty. Some consolation that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Expert: *Hi, how can I be of assistance?*
>   User: *I'm interested in the Turing Test*
>   Expert: *You're not the only one who is interested in the turing test.*
>   User: *Are you then?*
>   Expert: *On the internet, nobody knows you're then.*
>   User: *Come again?*
>   Expert: *On a slightly related note, you should try to have a difference in driving ability.*
>   User: *I take it you're not too bothered about passing a Turing Test then?*
>   Expert: *Nobody asked me to be too bothered about passing a turing test then.*
>   User: *Just as well, since I'm coming to the conclusion you've already failed the test! :)*
>
> Expert: *I used to know someone who was coming to the conclusion **me've already failed the test.***

Answer (score 4):

> **User:** What can you help with?
>   **Expert:** That's a secret.
>   **User:** You're not much help, then.
>   **Expert:** I don't get paid for being much help.
>   **User:** Ah. So we get what you're paid for.
>   **Expert:** I can't answer that.
>   **User:** So what can you do?
>   **Expert:** That depends.
>   **User:** How is hunger satisfied?
>   **Expert:** Why do you want to know?
>   **User:** There's a question on a Stack Exchange site.
>   **Expert:** O... kay...
>   **User:** Are you waiting to see what the answer is?
>   **Expert:** That depends.
>   **User:** I was hoping I would speak to an expert.
>   **Expert:** It's easy to become an expert; it's hard to be one.
>   **User:** QED